# load py file from path/folder

Tags: python, python-import

I busy with some calculations in Python and therefore i have some bunch of scripts.
I have tried to clean this up thru 2 folders named `scripts` and `tests`.
Now i have the problem that my main Python file don't recognize the scripts in the subfolders.
So my `import filename` don't work anny more. When i look in some git files it looks like the don mention paths and still it works.
I had looked at [this SE question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder-in-python) but that gave me a error (`ImportError: No module named "filename"`)

What have i to do in my main script, subfolder or files in subfolders.

my scripts are no classes yet... Probably not all become classes. so a generic solution is best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do relative imports from where you are. Let's assume you're importing from the file `/home/janbert/projects/test/test.py`

If  you want to import `/home/janbert/projects/test/subdir/file.py` you write:

```
from subdir import file
```

And if you want to import `/home/janbert/projects/otherproject/subdir/file.py` you write:

```
from ..otherproject.subdir import file
```

Just remember that each python package (ie folder) must have a file named `__init__.py` (which can be empty), otherwise you can not import from that package.

Comment: Is it in this way also possible to just run a file (no `def` in it)?
in this case that `file.py` runs it own script and don't put it back in the first one(generate some data; do something and create some figures)?

Comment: @Jan-Bert if you have code straight up in the imported file and not in functions in it it should be executed on import, just create an empty file with a print and see what happens. It's not advisable though, you should create functions and execute them explicitly instead.